# Icehrm - Cant able to login after local to server migration

Tags: php

I cant able to login after moving files icehrm from local to server.

Below is the only config file i changed in server,

```
define('CLIENT_NAME', 'app');
define('APP_BASE_PATH', '/home/xxx/public_html/example/');
define('CLIENT_BASE_PATH', '/home/xxx/public_html/rmsintranet/app/');
define('BASE_URL','http://example.com/icehrm/');
define('CLIENT_BASE_URL','http://example.com/icehrm/app/');

define('APP_DB', 'bd_name');
define('APP_USERNAME', 'bd_user');
define('APP_PASSWORD', 'db123');
define('APP_HOST', 'localhost');
define('APP_CON_STR', 'mysql://'.APP_USERNAME.':'.APP_PASSWORD.'@'.APP_HOST.'/'.APP_DB);

//file upload
define('FILE_TYPES', 'jpg,png,jpeg');
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE_KB', 10 * 1024);
```

Whenever i tried to login i'm getting login failed message

How to solve this? Is there any other config file need to update ?

Comment: Please do not **add** random `formatting` to *words* that you `think` might **be** important.  It makes your posts hard to read.  Also, please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: Please refer http://icehrm-blog.gamonoid.com/ice-hrm-manual-installation

Comment: @ThilinaHasantha Issue is with **case sensitive database table names**. All fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got my answer now able to run on server to icehrm
simply open `server.includes.inc.php` and comment line no :4:

```
include(APP_BASE_PATH.'lib/aws.phar');
```

Now your code will run smoothly

Comment: after two days long bug test find solution and feel happy to share :)

Comment: It's safe to comment this if you are not using Amazon SES for sending emails.